# How to inherit and add new state on a default module in odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

i am using odoo 10. Here i want to add an extra state in purchase module.Current states are open,draft and done. I want to add another state named new. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `selection_add` attribute.

Try below code:

```
state = fields.Selecion(selection_add=[('new_state','New State')])
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: What if I want to insert a state in the middle, the above solution will append the state at the end (in the form header)?